# How to create a resetable timer?

Tags: app-inventor

On the MIT App Inventor (similar but not the same to Scratch), I need to create a timer that can be reset when an action happens to complete an App. But, I have been unable to find a way to make a resetable timer. Is there a way using this piece of software? This is a link to the App [Inventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/).

The first 4 blocks are the codes for when the player interacts/clicks one of the 4 colored boxes.

The last block is the code outside of the 4 .Click blocks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is `set Clock.TimerEnabled = false` what you are looking for?

Comment: I might not understand the program to its fullest, but I need a timer that resets after each time the player scores a point, and if the player does not score in a certain time, do something.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks...

Comment: I added screenshots to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw. there is a lot of redundancy in your blocks, see Enis' tips [here](http://twodogapps.com/?page_id=686) how to simplify this...

If you want to reset the clock, just set `Clock.TimerEnabled = false` and then set 
`Clock.TimerEnabled = true` again and the clock will restart
see also the following example blocks (let's assume, you have a clock component and the timer interval is 10 seconds)

[image]

in the example I reset the clock after 5 seconds and as you can see, the clock starts from the beginning...

[image]

You can download the test project from [here](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/puravidaapps/reset.aia)

Comment: The actions are done at the end of the clock, right?

Comment: in the `Clock.Timer` event